# Jquery datepicker doesn't show selected date with featherlight JS

Tags: jquery, datepicker, featherlight.js

After going through all the post in stackoverflow, I still can't fix my issue.

I have featherlight JS running and using a jquery datepicker.

Below is my step by step explanation of what I am facing :

1) I have a button to trigger the featherlight to pop up
2) After clicking the button, I am able to click on the input field and open up the date picker
3) After selecting the date that I want, it is not showing the selected date in the input field
4) The featherlight pop up close when I clicked outside of the pop up
5) When I click on the button to trigger the featherlight to pop up again, it shows the previously selected date in the input field

Below are my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#dob").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
        });
    });

<a class='pure-button sign-up' data-featherlight='.overlay-signup'>Sign up</a>
<div class='overlay-signup'>
    <div class='holder-sm'>
        <div class='pure-u-1-1'>
            <div class='wrapper'>
                <h3>Sign up</h3>
                <p class="center-txt">Great prizes await! Sign up now!</p>
                <form method="post" action="index.php" name="registerform" class='pure-form pure-form-stacked'>
                    <fieldset>
                        <input id="user_name" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]{2,64}" name="user_name" class='pure-input-1' placeholder='NAME (as in NRIC)' type='text' required>

                        <div class="pure-g">
                            <div class="pure-u-2-3">
                                <input class='pure-input-1' id="dob" name="dob" placeholder='DATE OF BIRTH (DD/MM/YYYY)' type='text'>
                                <p class="dob"></p>
                                <!-- %input.pure-input-1{:type=>"text", :placeholder=>"Gender"} -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="pure-u-1-3">
                                <select class='pure-input-1' name="gender">
                                    <option value="Male">MALE</option>
                                    <option value="Female">FEMALE</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <input id="user_email" class='pure-input-1' placeholder='EMAIL (name@email.com)' type="email" name="user_email" required />

                        <input class='pure-input-1' placeholder='PASSWORD (at least 6 characters)'  id="user_password_new" type="password" name="user_password_new" pattern=".{6,}" required autocomplete="off" />

                        <input class='pure-input-1' placeholder='REPEAT PASSWORD' id="user_password_repeat" type="password" name="user_password_repeat" pattern=".{6,}" required autocomplete="off" />

                        <label class='pure-radio'>
                            <input checked='' name="newsletter" value="on" type='checkbox'>
                            I would like to receive promotions/newsletters from UNIQLO
                        </label>
                        <label class='pure-radio'>
                            <input type='checkbox' required>
                            I have read the <a href="tc.html">Terms & Conditions</a>
                        </label>
                    </fieldset>
                    <button class='pure-button' name="register" type='submit'>SIGN UP</button>
                    <p class="or">OR</p>
                    <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($loginUrl); ?>" class='pure-button' type='submit'>SIGN IN WITH FACEBOOK</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am very desperate now and have been trying to fix this issue for the past 5 hours.

Hope any kind souls will be able to help me out here.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `persist` option, or else tweak your javascript so your calendar binding occurs on `afterOpen`, without using an ID reference.

Comment: Hi Marc, I don't quite understand what do you mean. Tweaking my javascript, featherlight plugin or the datepicker?